# Ruby/Rails Filter JSON items per attribute via newest date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a JSON object like this

```
[{"id":"ad-34","date":"28.07.2016","value":"cheese"},
{"id":"ad-34","date":"31.07.2016","value":"cheese updated"},
{"id":"ad-21","date":"31.07.2016","value":"sausage updated"},
{"id":"ad-34","date":"02.08.2016","value":"cheese updated v2"}
{"id":"ad-21","date":"28.07.2016","value":"sausage"}]
```

and i want this:

```
[{"id":"ad-21","date":"31.07.2016","value":"sausage updated"},
{"id":"ad-34","date":"02.08.2016","value":"cheese updated v2"}]
```

So i need the latest version of `"id"` **only**. How can I manage that in Rails?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: 1. The penultimate line of your array needs a comma at the end. 2. Best to give the array a name (e.g., `arr = [{id:"ad-34"....` so readers can refer to it in answers and comments without having to define it. 3. Quotes around the key names are superfluous when using the `key: value` as opposed to `key => value` (unless the key contains whitespace); i.e., `arr = [{ id: "ad=-34", date: ...}`. 4. There is no need for the reference to JSON, as your question applies to arrays generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `array` is your array,

```
array.group_by { |h| h[:id] }.
    values.
    map { |arr| arr.max_by { |h| h[:date].split('.').reverse } }
  #=> [{:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"02.08.2016", :value=>"cheese updated v2"},
  #    {:id=>"ad-21", :date=>"31.07.2016", :value=>"sausage updated"}]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = array.group_by { |h| h[:id] }
  #=> {"ad-34"=>[{:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"28.07.2016", :value=>"cheese"},
  #              {:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"31.07.2016", :value=>"cheese updated"},
  #              {:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"02.08.2016", :value=>"cheese updated v2"}],
  #    "ad-21"=>[{:id=>"ad-21", :date=>"31.07.2016", :value=>"sausage updated"},
  #              {:id=>"ad-21", :date=>"28.07.2016", :value=>"sausage"}]} 
b = a.values
  #=> [[{:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"28.07.2016", :value=>"cheese"},
  #     {:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"31.07.2016", :value=>"cheese updated"},
  #     {:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"02.08.2016", :value=>"cheese updated v2"}],
  #    [{:id=>"ad-21", :date=>"31.07.2016", :value=>"sausage updated"},
  #     {:id=>"ad-21", :date=>"28.07.2016", :value=>"sausage"}]] 
b.map { |arr| arr.max_by { |h| h[:date].split('.').reverse } }
  #=> [{:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"02.08.2016", :value=>"cheese updated v2"},
  #    {:id=>"ad-21", :date=>"31.07.2016", :value=>"sausage updated"}]
```

In the last step the first value `map` passes to its block is

```
arr = b.first
  #=> [{:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"28.07.2016", :value=>"cheese"},
  #    {:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"31.07.2016", :value=>"cheese updated"},
  #    {:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"02.08.2016", :value=>"cheese updated v2"}]
```

so the block calculation is

```
arr.max_by { |h| h[:date].split('.').reverse }
  #=> {:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"02.08.2016", :value=>"cheese updated v2"}
```

To elaborate on the last calculation, the first value of `c` passed to the block is

```
h = arr.first
  #=> {:id=>"ad-34", :date=>"28.07.2016", :value=>"cheese"}
```

so the inner block calculation is

```
d = h[:date]
  #=> "28.07.2016"
e = d.split('.')
  #=> ["28", "07", "2016"] 
e.reverse
  #=> ["2016", "07", "28"]
```

The two other hashes for `id: "ad-34"` are processed similarly. `arr.max_by` computes

```
[["2016", "07", "28"], ["2016", "07", "31"], ["2016", "02", "08"]].max
  #=> ["2016", "07", "31"]
```

and therefore selects `c[1]`. The calculations for `b[1]` are similar.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use something like:

```
@variabel = Model.all.order("ID ASC") and the, call a method that compares the id.
```

For exmple:

```
def compare_id
 if @variable.id == latest
  do something
end
```

The method is just a basic idea, but you can implement something with real code in order to accomplish what you need

Answer (score 0):

I think we just update entry by entry to a hash with structure `|key, value| = |id, entry|` then we just get the values of the hash result. The code will be like:

```
input = your_json_input
output = {}.tap do |my_hash|
  json.each{ |entry| input[entry['id']] = entry }
end.values
```

So the latest entry of id will be in the `my_hash`